# Android Communication through ad-hoc

Tags: android, bluetooth, communication, adhoc

I need Communication for my android applications to send and receive some messages without using internet and server. I think I should use something like ad-hoc or bluetooth but I have no idea which is better and where to start. can anyone show me a way to start?

Comment: please share what you have tried first.

Comment: @SaravInfern I have a realtime application which uses client server protocol for communication. now i want to change this to local wifi and adhoc to get rid of my server. i didn't tried anything about this before and i started from asking a question here

Comment: please look at this [google sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/project.html) which uses bluetooth for implementing chat.

Comment: @SaravInfern thank you, i will. in my case bluetooth is the second option because it connects only two devices. i want more devices connects to each other in same time.

Comment: look at this [sample](https://github.com/life0fun/wifi-direct-chat) which uses wifi for chat